# SO(n) bi-invariant metric

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

Prove that the induced metric on SO(n) is bi-invariant. The inner product is given by the Frobenius inner product on matrices.

Comment: Writing in the imperative is a good way to ensure people do not respond to your posts.

Comment: @RyanBudney mathematicians are treated so rudely compared to computer people.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint 1**:$\quad$ Note that for invertible matrices $A$ and $B$, which way you multiply two matrices does not affect the trace, i.e. $\mathrm{tr}(AB)=\mathrm{tr}(BA)$ (*do you see why?*), hence the trace is similarity-invariant: $$\mathrm{tr}(A^{-1}BA)=\mathrm{tr}((BA)A^{-1})=\mathrm{tr}(B(AA^{-1}))=\mathrm{tr}(B).$$

**Hint 2**:$\quad$ In $SO$ (or $O$ for that matter), what relationship do $A^T$ and $A^{-1}$ have to each other?

---

Now you should be able to check both left and right invariance with direct computations.