# Are one-parameter subgroups of compact, embedded Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, geodesic

Let $(G,\circ)$ be a Lie group, where $G\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ is a compact, smooth manifold. I call the neutral element $e$.

I figured that there exists a bi-invariant metric on $G$ and I also figured that then one parameter subgroups are geodesics.

Is for every $p\in G$, $v\in T_eG$ and sufficiently small $a,b\geq 0$ the curve
$$ \gamma: [-a,b] \to G,\qquad t\mapsto p\circ\exp(t v)$$
the shortest curve on $G$ that connects $\gamma(-a)$ and $\gamma(b)$ with respect to the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: The answer is no for sure if you do not say how $G$ sits inside $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: I don't quite understand, can you explain this further?

Comment: For example, let $G$ be $k$-dimensional. Then one can deform $G$ in such a way that $G$ lies completely in a $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ for some open set $U \subset G$ containing $e$, so that the none of the one parameter groups are straight lines.

Comment: This does not work already for the circle...

Comment: The idea is that on $G$ you have the metric given by the bi-invariant metric and the metric given by restricting the Euclidean metric to $G$. No assumption is made between these two metrics, thus there is no hope that they are related.

Comment: I think it works for the circle, why shouldn't it?
Is there hope that it will work for some special, easy Lie groups?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez : I think it works for the circle. In that case the induced metric is the bi-invariant metric.

Comment: @Wauzl: Unless the Lie group is one dimensional, I cannot see why this is true.

Comment: If G sits in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ "naturally", then the induced metric should be bi-invariant. See this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69434/son-bi-invariant-metric